# MYSQL Function with a calcuation based on data in a db column

Tags: mysql

I Have a table that is a lookup for scoring points based on Place (P) and Number of Racers(R)
and scoring formats indicated by points_id. Two cases are shown in the table.
Sometime the points are determined directly by the values of P and N as in points_id =3
other times they are most easily determined by a simple calculation shown in the pts_calc column.

```
|points_id| P | N |points|pts_calc|    
|    1    | 0 | 0 | NULL | pin    |
|    1    |DNS| 0 | NULL | nin+1  |
|    3    | 1 | 0 |102.00| NULL   |
|    3    | 2 | 0 | 98.00| NULL   |
|    3    | 3 | 0 | 96.00| NULL   |
|    3    | 4 | 0 | 93.00| NULL   |
|    3    | 5 | 0 | 91.00| NULL   |
|    3    | 6 | 0 | 89.00| NULL   |
|    3    |DNF| 0 | 85.00| NULL   |
```

I was hoping to create a function that returned the points from the three input variables.
points_id, P, N.
Below is what I tried.

```
CREATE FUNCTION POINTS(pid INT,pin VARCHAR(3),nin INT)
RETURNS DEC(6,2)
DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
DECLARE pts DECIMAL(6,2);
DECLARE pcalc VARCHAR(20);

SELECT points,pts_calc INTO pts,pcalc FROM scoring_points WHERE points_id=pid AND (P=pin OR P='0') AND (N=nin or N=0); 

IF(pts IS NULL) THEN
SET @s= CONCAT('SET pts = ',pcalc);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;

END IF;

RETURN pts;

END
```

But i got this error.

## 1336 - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Further research show the Prepare statement is not allowed in functions only but procedures.
I was hoping to do something like;

```
SELECT SUM(Points(pid,place,numb)) FROM t1 GROUP BY racer.id
```

But onto plan B (tbd) unless someone has great idea.

Comment: Taking a step back, how does this component fit in with your application?  Your data structure strikes me as rather odd.

Comment: Fair enough,  It does look weird but for 2 reasons,  One the scoring systems are all very different, and two it is missing case two where there are distinct point values for differnt P and N combos.  eg you get 100 points for 1 place in a group of 10 racers, you only get 75 pts when you are 1 place out of two.  That is what is driving the data structure.  The calculation thing is an attempt to not have to replicate many rows for the case when there is a mathematical relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might fare better having three numeric columns instead of your `pts_calc` column:

1. `cPIN` - coefficient of `pin` term
2. `cNIN` - coefficient of `nin` term
3. `cnst` - constant term

Your function could then perform:

```
SELECT IFNULL(points, cPIN*pin + cNIN*nin + cnst) INTO pts
FROM scoring_points
WHERE ...
```

Depending on your needs, you might even be able to get rid of the `points` column by just using `cnst` and leaving the other two equal to 0.

Comment: Was coming to the same conclusion, not as flexible but should be fast and get the job done.  Thanks Dave